# Prove that $\gcd(4k, 2k+1)=1$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

As part of solving a problem in elementary number theory, I got to this condition which I'd like to prove.

I went about it as follows:

If $d=\gcd(4k, 2k+1)$ then $4k \equiv 0 \equiv 2k+1\pmod d$ and therefore $0 \equiv 2(2k+1) - 4k \equiv 2\pmod d$, whence $d \mid 2$. Therefore either $d = 1$ or $d = 2$.

However, clearly d cannot be 2 since $2k+1$ is an odd number, therefore it must be that $d = 1$, QED.

This seems to prove the result, however I am bothered by the fact I cannot find a representation of d ($=1$) in the form $1 = ax + by$ for x, y integers where $a=4k$ and $b=2k+1$.
I would expect to be able to find such an identity given [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).. what am I missing?

Comment: Hint: $a$ and $b$ may involve $k$

Comment: @Empy2 aha I think I follow - this is really finding a gcd of two *polynomials* (albeit of degree 1), hence the form of Bezout's identity relevant here is one where the co-efficients x and y may be polynonimals themselves (although still only involving whole numbers per my needs)

Comment: If you like, yes.  But I was thinking the solution for $4$ and $3$ will be different from $8$ and $5$, or $12$ and $7$, and you might spot a pattern in the $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $(\color{#0a0}{1-2k})(1+2k) = 1 - 4k(\color{#c00}k) = $ Bezout equation for $\,\gcd(1+2k,4k),\,$ by  



$\bmod 2k+1\!:\ 2k\equiv -1\Rightarrow (2k^2)\equiv 1\Rightarrow 1/4k\equiv \color{#c00}k.\ $ **Or, alternatively**



$\!\bmod 4k\!:\ \color{#c00}{(2k)^2\equiv 0}\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{1\!+\!2k}\equiv\dfrac{1}{1\!+\!2k}\dfrac{1\!-\!2k}{1\!-\!2k}\equiv \dfrac{\color{#0a0}{1\!-\!2k}}{1\!-\!\color{#c00}{(2k)^2}}$ by [$\rm\color{#c00}{nilpotent}$ simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242)

Comment: The first method is explained in the first linked dupe, ie. $2k$ is a unit (invertible) hence so too is its  (square) power $(2k)^2$ hence so too is its factor $4k$, with inverse being its cofactor $k = (2k)^2/(4k)$. The second method uses a generalization of rationaling the denominator to invert a unit + nilpotent, see the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242).

Comment: Above we used that computing the Bezout equation is equivalent to computing modular inverses, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) the third dupe.

Comment: **Or** apply the (polynomial) extended Euclidean algorithm as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3140261/242) in the fourth dupe, viewing the gcd args as polynomials in $\,k.\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=-(k+1), y=(2k+1)$

$$4kx+(2k+1)y=-4k(k+1)+(2k+1)^2=1$$

Comment: Simpler: the Bezout identity is $(1-2k)(1+2k) = 1-4k(k)\,$ which is easily *discovered* by [general methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4680189/prove-that-gcd4k-2k1-1-for-k-in-mathbb-z#comment9896666_4680189) (vs, pulling it out of a hat like magic as above).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).